# onclick attribute not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery file as follow :

```
$('.font').click(function(){
        for(i=0;i<FontArray.length;i++){
            var font = FontArray[i]; 
            $('#view_container').append("<button class='b_font' id='"+font+"' onclick='saveMe("+font+");'>"+font+"</button>");
            $('.'+font).css('font-family',font);
        }
        // event.preventDefault();
    });
```

And the function **saveMe** is defined as follow :

```
function saveMe(font){
        alert(font);
    }
```

But when i click any of the button i get the following error :
 **Uncaught ReferenceError: saveMe is not defined**

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create jsfiddle with code for this issue

Comment: Are you defining `saveMe` in the top level scope?

Comment: This should work as long as you have the saveMe method defined in the script block which is available to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
onclick='saveMe("+font+");'
```

renders as

```
onclick='saveMe(arial);'
```

So when you click on it, it is looking for a variable `arial` not the string `"arial"`. You need to quote it.

```
onclick='saveMe(\""+font+"\");'
```

Now for saveMe not being defined, that needs to have more context. When is saveMe defined? If it is inside of a document ready/window onload method, than you need to put it outside of it so it is available in window scope.

And the line

```
$('.'+font).css('font-family',font);
```

Should probably be

```
$('#'+font).css('font-family',font);
```

Comment: Now error is resolved but no value is getting alerted . Can you help me out in that

Comment: Sorry my bad ! i didnt read the answer fully , just saw the coding ! my function was inside the document.ready block ... moved the function outside the block and now error is resolved !

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is where the `saveMe` function is defined. `onclick` has only access to global scope and that's there the fuction would have to be for this solution to work.

That'd be a quick workaround:

```
window.saveMe = function (font){
    alert(font);
}
```

However, you should note that cluttering global scope is usually undesirable and quickly leads to errors. It's better to attach events to selected elements by using `.click()`. In your code - you can attach the element and then bind click event to it.

```
var $button = $("<button class='b_font' id='"+font+"' onclick='saveMe("+font+");'>"+font+"</button>");
$('#view_container').append($button);
$button.click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

**EDIT:** As [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) also pointed out - the string is not escaped properly

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `saveMe` is out of scope, you probably put it inside the DOM ready handler.

As you're using jQuery, why not use it, and get rid of those inline event handlers

```
$(function() {

    $('.font').click(function() {
        $('#view_container').append(
            $.map(FontArray, function(index, font) {
                return $('<button />', {
                            'class' : 'b_font',
                            id      : font,
                            on      : { click : saveMe },
                            css     : { fontFamily : font }
                })
            })
        )
    });

    function saveMe() {...}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add this code and get rid of the code in the markup:

```
$('#view_container').on('click','.b_font',function(){
  saveMe($(this).text());
});
```

OR perhaps better make this change:

```
$('#view_container').append("<button class='b_font' id='"+font+"' data-fontsave='"+font+"'>"+font+"</button>");
```

then this works and is less prone to error perhaps:

```
$('#view_container').on('click','.b_font',function(){
  saveMe($(this).data('fontsave'));
});
```